# Is a Public Exit TorRelay on or off by default?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays, exit-relays

Looking at this [releases for windows](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en): 
Are in any of these releases public exits on by default?

In his [post @SamWhited](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4558/windows-tor-browser-bundle-check-if-relays-is-off) assumed that they are off.

But looking at Point g of [Configuring a Tor Relay](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay.html.en):

> If you want to allow others to use your relay for these services, don't change anything. Un-check the services you don't want to allow people to reach from your relay. If you want to be a non-exit relay, un-check all services.

So these bundles generate an exit policy by default?

I just feel a little panic because I'm, unsure weather i could have installed the bridge bundle a week ago instead of the browser bundle and that this could have resulted in an accidental public tor exit :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The releases for Windows consist of several subpackages:

- Tor Browser
- Vidalia Bridge Bundle
- Vidalia Relay Bundle
- *Vidalia Exit Bundle*
- Expert Bundle

The package in italic (*Vidalia Exit Bundle*) is the one which is configured as exit by default.

The Tor Browser is just a client. The Vidalia Bridge Bundle configures Tor as a bridge, which is kind of a hidden entry point and the Vidalia Relay Bundle configures Tor as a non-exit.

The description at the page [Configuring your Tor Relay](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay.html.en) is insofar not fully exact.